# C++ How do I convert int to hex char (as in 0x0A, not "0A")

Tags: c++, char, hex

Sorry if this is hard to understand :P I'm trying to convert a decimal int value to a char value so I can write it in binary mode with fstream in c++. I did this: `char hexChar = 0x01; file.write(hexChar, size);`. That worked fine until I needed to write a decimal int from user. My question is, how do I convert decimal int to char hex value like this: `int decInt = 10; char hexChar = 0x00; hexChar = decInt; file.write(hexChar, size);` PS: I've been googling this for about an hour, and haven't found an answer. Every other solved problem with this has been decimal to ASCII hex value like "0A" using cout, not 0x0A using fstream.

Comment: There"s no such thing as "decimal int value". There are just int values. And there are character strings which are decimal representations of int values. Likewise for char values, there are no hex char values.

Comment: You don't have to convert it. It's already stored as it needs to be. If you're having a problem, describe the problem, not the solution you don't know how to implement.

Comment: This sounds insane. Use `std::ofstream`. Then you can do `file << myChar << myInt` to write them both in a single line. KISS.

Comment: It sounds like you have a lot of confusions between numbers and representations of numbers. Numbers are things like the number of toes you have, which can be represented as "ten", "10", "111111111" or any number of other ways.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz _'It sounds like you have a lot of confusions between numbers and representations of numbers.'_ Yes, I met this often with beginners over here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't matter which kind of literal you are using to initialize an `int` variable

```
int x = 0x0A;
int y = 10;
```

The above statements assign the exactly same value to the variables.

To output numeric values with hexadecimal base representation you can use the [`std::hex`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/hex/) I/O stream manipulator:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>


int main() {
    int x = 10; // equivalents to 0x0A
    int y = 0x0A; // equivalents to 10

    std::cout << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0') 
              << "x = " << std::hex <<  "0x" << x << std::endl;
    std::cout << "y = " << std::dec << y << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
x = 0xa
y = 10
```

See the live sample [here](http://ideone.com/PJcOai).